# how to send flash logout message express or check if redirected

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, middleware, flash-message

Hello guys I have this `server.js` setup, and im trying to pass msg "logged out successfully" on `/login` page when user will log out. The problem here is that im using so much middleware and I'm kinda lost in what's going on. I tried to pass it by res.locals, req.session, req.session.flash,  but some method or middleware probably is deleting sessions.

Something is going on in `.delete()` method probably, because everything seems to work just fine if im passing variables outside of this method. Seems like maybe .delete()/method_override middleware has some features that I dont know about OR i cannot use next() properly.  Help guys i spent so much time on this already.

Alternatively, if you could tell me, how to check if i was redirected to `/login` then I could easily figure out some work arounds but right now im stucked. Also is there any better way of passing that message? Should I use queries for this example? I'm kinda perfectionist and don't like this ugly urls :D

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const users = []

const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const passport = require('passport')
const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
initializePassport(passport,   
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    name => users.find(user => user.name === name))


app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})) 
app.use(flash())            
app.use(session({               
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,         
    resave: false,                        
    saveUninitialized: false              
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method')) 


app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.test)                   //> undefined
    res.render('login', { msg: req.flash('info')})  //> undefined
})


app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut((err) => err ? next(err) : '')
    req.flash('info', 'logged out successfully')  // ? 
    req.session.test = true;                 // ?
    res.redirect('/login')
})


function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next){ 
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved with 2 different workarounds:**   *(besides the easy but not the prettiest one - passing query in an url)*

#### 1. setting `global.location`

*need to check (global.location === 'logout') in latter method, then delete global.location*

#### 2. redirecting to GET method first, then passing msg to `flash()`

```
// app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {                    //  2
//     req.flash('info', 'Logged out succesfully')
//     res.redirect('/login')
// })

app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {                
    req.logOut((err) => err ? next(err) : void(0))
    global.location = 'logout'       //  1  -> 
    res.redirect('/login')
    // res.redirect('/logout)
})
```

Seems like flash() .locals, .session and others simply doesn't work in .delete function with method-override.